# KVM : Connect USB PS3 Eye Webcam to Virtual Machine

Tags: virtualization, webcam, kvm-virtualization

General Question: 
What keeps a USB device from registering correctly in a KVM virtual machine?

Specific:
The PS3 Eye (ID 1415:2000 Nam Tai E&E Products Limited or OmniVision Technologies, Inc Sony Playstation Eye), works fine on the host system.

I'm trying to connect various webcams to a vm running Ubuntu 14.04 (kernel 3.16.0-41 that is same as version I have on the host). I'm using Virtual Machine Manager 0.9.5 as frontend. I am able to connect all but one, which is the PS Eye, to the virtual machine.
While it stops to be available to the host it doesn't show up on:

```
    guest:lsusb
```

(other devices do show up)